# Axios async problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios

I have this axios call with a nested axios call that causes async problems. Here's a simplifyed snippet of my code:

```
axios.all([
    axios.get('https://foo..', {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/bar..' },
    }),
]).then(axios.spread((resp) => {
    var resp = resp.data.content;
    var items = resp.items.slice(0, 1);
    items.forEach(item => {
        var dataUrl = item.url.split('/v2/').slice(1).join('');
        axios.get('https://foo..', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/' + dataUrl + 'bar..' }
        }).then(resp => {
            const data = resp.data.content;
            // alot of code goes here
        }
        )
    }),
       axios.get('https://foo..' + pageNum.toString(), {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: {}
        }
        ).then(resp => {
            fillTemplate(resp.data.content[0].xml);                   
        }
        ).catch(function (error) { console.log("DB-GET-Error:\n" + error) });
})
).catch(function (error) { console.log("error " + error) });
```

The problem is that 'fillTemplate()' executes before 'items.forEach(...)' is done and can populate 'fillTemplate()' with data, how can I solve this?

Comment: either use async/await or execute last request in then() of a last request from for each

Comment: @MilanMarkovic I looked up async/await in tutorials but couldn't figure out how to implement it into my code, do you have an example how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

Both requests are send async and second won't wait for first one. Solution is to use **async/await** or [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

**Escaping the callback hell**

You are still having the problem of deeply nested code, which becomes unreadable. Below are two examples, first just fixing the issue and second with better readability.

**Sample Code**

```
axios.all([
  axios.get('https://foo..', {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/bar..' },
  }),
]).then(axios.spread((resp) => {
  // cache axios promises here
  var promises = []
  var resp = resp.data.content;
  var items = resp.items.slice(0, 1);
  items.forEach(item => {
      var dataUrl = item.url.split('/v2/').slice(1).join('');
      var promise = axios.get('https://foo..', {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/' + dataUrl + 'bar..' }
      }).then(resp => {
          const data = resp.data.content;
          // alot of code goes here
      });

      // add promises to array
      promises.push(promise);
  });

  // wait for all promises to execute next request
  Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    axios.get('https://foo..' + pageNum.toString(), {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: {}
  }).then(resp => {
      fillTemplate(resp.data.content[0].xml);                   
  }).catch(function (error) { console.log("DB-GET-Error:\n" + error) });
  });
})).catch(function (error) { console.log("error " + error) });
```

**Refactored version**

```
axios.all([doStuff()]).then(axios.spread((resp) => {
  var promises = []
  var resp = resp.data.content;
  var items = resp.items.slice(0, 1);
  items.forEach(item => {
      var dataUrl = item.url.split('/v2/').slice(1).join('');
      var promise = doOtherStuff();
      promises.push(promise);
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(finalCallback).then(resp => {
    fillTemplate(resp.data.content[0].xml);                   
  });
}));

function doStuff() {
  return axios.get('https://foo..', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/bar..' },
  });
}

function doOtherStuff() {
  return axios.get('https://foo..', {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: { 'endpoint': 'v2/' + dataUrl + 'bar..' }
  }
}

function finalCallback(results) {
  return axios.get('https://foo..' + pageNum.toString(), {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    data: {}
  });
}
```